# Como abrir uma tela com formulário pré preenchido com PHP e HTML?

Tags: php, html, html5

Boa noite a todos,
eu gostaria de saber como abrir um formulário cujos campos já estejam previamente preenchidos com os dados do usuário(resultantes de uma pesquisa no banco de dados), ficando a cargo dele somente editar as informações. Pesquisei na internet e encontrei uma forma, mas seria gerando o HTML do formulário todo via comando *echo* do PHP; entretanto li que isso não é uma boa prática de programação... há alguma forma de fazer isso de maneira que respeite as boas práticas?

Comment: Use o atributo `value` para colocar os valores no formulário: `<input value="João da Silva">` se for `select` coloque o atributo `selected` no `option` e.g: `<select><option value="H" selected>Homem</selected>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria interessante você ter no atributo "value" uma referência para uma variável, então toda vez que você carregasse os dados do banco você atribuiria os valores.
Por exemplo:

Você chamaria a página passando os valores na requisição:

```
    <?php

    function __autoload($class) {

        if (file_exists("../app.ado/{$class}.class.php")) {
            include_once "../app.ado/{$class}.class.php";
        }
    }

    // Verifica se exitem valores passados na requisição - A mesma página serve para cadastro e edição,
    //  quando é aberta sem nenhum valor passado é para cadastro, caso contrário é edição
    if (empty($_REQUEST)) {
        // Variáveis que estão referenciadas nas textbox
        $id = "";
        $nome = "";
        $emailContato = "";
        $idInstituicaoEnsino = "";
        $tipo = "";
    } else {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $nome = $_REQUEST['nome'];
        $emailContato = $_REQUEST['emailContato'];
        $idInstituicaoEnsino = $_REQUEST['idInstituicaoEnsino'];
        $tipo = $_REQUEST['tipo'];
    }

    ?>
```

E depois temos o html:

```
    <form method="post" action="controller.php">
                    <table><!-- Campos de preenchimento-->
                        <!-- Identificação-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Identificação 
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="_id"
                                       value="<?= $id ?>"
                                       placeholder="Id Numérico" 
                                       size="10" title="Numero que identifica o curso"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--Nome-->
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Nome
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="_nome"
                                       value="<?= $nome ?>"
                                       placeholder="Nome do curso" 
                                       size="50" title="Nome do curso"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr> ... E assim por diante
```

Comment: curti essa ideia, mas e o código para setar essa variável, ele ficaria no mesmo arquivo juntamente com o html? ou tem como eu fazer separado e somente referenciar?

Comment: Para atribuir os valores pode ser em um bloco php na sua página, onde você irá declarar essas variáveis e invocar os método para a consulta. Agora a lógica da consulta e tudo mais pode ser em um arquivo separado, como boa prática, para separar html de php.

Comment: Se quiser em tenho um exemplo que fiz há um tempo.

Comment: se vc puder, eu quero ver sim, mt obrigado

Comment: De nada. Editei a resposta com o exemplo do código.

Answer (score 1):

A estrtura para pré-preencher informação de um formulário HTML é realmente muito simples, ainda mais usando PHP.

```
<?php
  $nome_html = htmlspecialchars( $nome );
  $email_html = htmlspecialchars( $email );
?>

<form name="meuForm" method="post" id="formulario">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="input_text"
           name="nome" id="name"
           value="<?= $nome_html ?>" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text"
           class="input_text"
           name="email" id="email"
           value="<?= $email_html ?>" />
    <input type="button"
           class="button"
           value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Algumas dicas:

1. Faça o quoting [htmlspecialchars($variável)](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlspecialchars.php) das variáveis, para não correr o risco do seu HTML ser pixado pelo conteúdo de sua variável.
2. Evite usar estrutura de tabelas `<table>` para organizar seu formulário, prefira estrutura [tableless](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-criar-formularios-html-sem-usar-tabelas-tableless/28278), que deixam seu código muito mais organizado, separando o design e organização em um arquivo CSS.